# I have an outlet adapter that is clicking at 260bpm. What is happening?

Tags: mains, acoustic-noise

I plugged this adapter, [GE Grounded Adapter-Spaced Six-Outlet Tap](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B011BX90CI), into my outlet the other day. I noticed a clicking noise in my apartment, and it's coming from the adaptor. I used an online app to measure its BPM. 260 BPM. But 260 isn't an even multiple of 60 or 120 (I live in the US).

Can anyone explain what might be happening?

[image]

Comment: If it's plugged in and unloaded (not delivering much power to anything) it's probably turning on, topping up its stored charge, and turning off again. Several times a second.

Comment: @BrianDrummond The linked device is not a power supply, so that can't be it.

Comment: "But 260 isn't an even multiple of 60 or 120 ..." A multiple of 60 Hz would be a multiple of 60 beats *per second* or 3600 beats per minute.

Comment: To clarify: does this happen with the adapter plugged into the wall but nothing plugged into the adapter?

Comment: Bad contact and arcing? If you wiggle it a bit, does it change frequency or go away?

Comment: If your duplex outlet has split wiring then there could be some serious short circuit happening. Then, if there are resettable fuses inside they could be making that noise.

Comment: @replete when nothing is plugged in, it still makes the noise...when I unplug it, the clicking speeds up, then stops

Comment: @dougvk with "when I unplug it", I take you mean both sides, right?

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes - once i take it out, it speeds up clicking, then totally stops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is purely an adapter, i.e. there should be no components in there that go "click".

This points to the adapter sparking internally, or at the plug. That should not happen. Return the device. You link to a product page of the adapter that's only available through third-party seller on amazon, and these are known to sometimes ship counterfeits. I wouldn't know how to make an adapter cheaper by decreasing conductor distances, but maybe these were factory rejects? (Pretty sure that GE tests everything they put on the market for arcing)

The 260 bpm are probably a measurement error; 60 Hz is 3600 bpm, and that's probably much faster than that app expects, and thus, you get a bogus beat estimate. Try with something less music-centric instead, e.g. the Phyphox app, which comes with audio spectrum plots.

You commented later on:

> @replete when nothing is plugged in, it still makes the noise...when I unplug it, the clicking speeds up, then stops

Um, what? This is really supposed to be a passive device; there should be nothing inside to produce clicking after **completely** disconnecting it (I assume you have nothing plugged into the in-, and power output side).

This invalidates my answer: there's something about this device that is *more* than just an adapter. (PLEASEPLEASEPLEASE don't be something obnoxious.)

Comment: GE does make these.  They licence the GE name to other companies.  Friend of mine worked for the licensing group for a time.

Comment: I'd really assume that of you're in the business of renting out your logo/reputation, you'd make the users of your name be sure to deliver intact, safe devices. That's why I still think the specific, individual adapter OP has might just look like a licensed GE product.

Comment: What meant to say was "does NOT make these".

Comment: you are right, it was sparking much faster

Comment: @dougvk I'm really worried about you saying that it continues to click after unplugging it

Comment: The device is busted anyway. Why don't you open it up and see what's inside. I bet a lot of people on this thread dying to know that :)

Comment: @Maple i will open it up. unplugged completely, and ordered a new one